# manually convert input parameters in type instance

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have some problem to save date value in varchar field.
I'm trying to convert an input date (like 17/06/2015) to an Time instance and then store it in my database as 2015-06-17

here an exemple of the entity which i want to save

```
(int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Valeur) {
    'new' => true,
    'accessible' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'caracteristique_id' => (int) 51,
        'caracteristique' => object(App\Model\Entity\Caracteristique) {
            'new' => true,
            'accessible' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'id' => (int) 51,
                'type' => 'Date'
            ],
            'dirty' => [
                'id' => true,
                'type' => true
            ],
            'original' => [],
            'virtual' => [],
            'errors' => [],
            'repository' => 'Caracteristiques'
        },
        'valeur' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
            'time' => '2015-06-03T10:28:53+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false                             
        }
    ],
    'dirty' => [
        'caracteristique_id' => true,
        'caracteristique' => true,
        'valeur' => true
    ],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'Valeurs'                       
},
```

After save i only got 17/06/2015 in my database

Comment: Are you _really_ sure that this value is in your database, and not just what is being displayed in the view in a formatted fashion? I'd kinda doubt that such a value makes it to the database, not only should the DBMS reject such a value for a date/time-ish column (MYSQL for example would store `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for a DATETIME column), but also the CakePHP time related database type classes do format the value to a DB compatible format before it is being saved (see [`DateTimeType::toDatabase()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.7/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php#L86)).

Comment: Yeah i'm sure i'm working with PHPStorm so i have access to my database rows

Comment: Next time please provide the whole picture, the fact that, and the reason why you are using a VARCHAR column for a date value is kinda important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just save as a datetime and format when using it in a view, but what you could do is before saving (either in the beforeSave or in the Controller/model) altering the value to match whatever date you want

Assuming that your entity is called valeur and the field where you store your date is also valeur:

```
$valeur->valeur = $valeur->valeur->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i found an answer in timestamp behavior so i did that in my entity:

```
protected function _setValeur($valeur)
{
    if (isset($this->caracteristique)) {
        if ($this->caracteristique->isDate()) {
            try {
                if (!($valeur instanceof Time)) {
                    $valeur = Time::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $valeur);
                }
                return $valeur->format('Y-m-d');
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($valeur)) {
        $valeur = null;
    }
    return $valeur;
}

protected function _getValeur($valeur)
{
    if (isset($this->caracteristique)) {
        if ($this->caracteristique->isDate()) {
            try {
                return Time::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $valeur);
            } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return $valeur;
}

protected function _getDate()
{
    if (isset($this->caracteristique)) {
        if ($this->caracteristique->isDate()) {
            return !is_null($this->valeur) ?
                $this->valeur->format('d/m/Y') : $this->valeur;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

the field valeur is typed dynamically referenced by the caracteristic association so even if in my db the valeur's field is a varchar in the app it can be a date, string or numeric.

In this case i test the type then i just retrieve Time object on find and i set to date string with the format 'd/m/Y' when i'm saving.

i also create a virtual property which give me formated date